# Yii2 gridview relation data search for all column

Tags: gridview, foreign-keys, yii2

In my requirment i want to list the gridview with relational data, i have a two table tbl_work(id,workid,cdr_id(foreign_key of tbl_cd)) and tbl_cd(id,caller,called).

in work model and cd model having hasone relation.
then i was created a grid with the tb_work table and show the tbl_cd table records.

**search function in work model**

```
$query = AuditorWorkItems::find();
        $query->with("cd");

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'id' => $this->id,
        'workid' => $this->workid,
        'cdr_id' => $this->cdr_id
    ]);

        return $dataProvider;
```

in my grid

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'columns' => [
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
                [
                'attribute' => 'cdr_id',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                    return $model->cdr->called;

                },
            ],
           [

                'attribute' => 'cdr_id',
                'value' => function ($model) {
                    return $model->cdr->caller;
                },
            ],
```

Its show the called and caller value but filter is not working, do you have any other idea to implement this with all the column in tbl_cd table

Comment: post your full code of search method.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Step 1 :

Define a variable in your search model:

```
public $calledValue;
```

Step 2 :

In rules apply the required rule.

```
[['calledValue'], 'safe'],
```

Step 3 :

If you want to sort data with respect to that column in your search model before loading parameters write this code :

```
$dataProvider->sort->attributes['calledValue'] =
    [
    'asc' => ['tbl_cd.called' => SORT_ASC], // TABLE_NAME.COLUMN_NAME
    'desc' => ['tbl_cd.called' => SORT_DESC],
    ];
```

Step 4 :

Now to filter the data add this code in your grid filtering conditions.

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'tbl_cd.called', $this->calledValue]);
```

Step 5 :

Now in your Index file write this code :

```
[
'attribute' => 'calledValue', //To display called value
'label' => 'Your Label',
'value' => 'tbl_cd.called'
],
```